# Android Emulator option is not coming in Titanium Studio

Tags: android, titanium, android-2.2-froyo, titanium-alloy

I have installed titanium studio and installed Android SDK also in Windows. After that I have created one test application. When I right click on the project folder to run the application I cannot find the `Android Emulator` option.

[image]

What can I do now. I am not able to test `hello world` app. Any help please.

Comment: what is the 6th option `titanium_1_WVGA800`? It seems to be like its an emulator.

Comment: I have tried with that. this error is coming - `[ERROR] :  Failed to install apk on emulator-5554`
`[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1`

Comment: Have you installed required Android SDK version?

Comment: yes .. I have installed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correctly spotted Swanand !!! Emulator is in the list,D' Scolz you just need to start your emulator from Titanium Studio .And try to run your app when emulator is in running state!!!hope it works for you ..